# Service configuration not injected into custom JSON layout

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard project where I have a class that I am extending from the JsonLayout class provided by Logback, in order to define my own custom JSON layout for log messages. I am overriding the toJsonMap method of Logback.

```
public class LogEventJsonLayout extends JsonLayout {

@Setter(onMethod = @__({@Inject}))
private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = null;

@Override
protected Map toJsonMap(final ILoggingEvent event) {
.....
}
}
```

In the above class, I want to use some parameters that I specified via my application.yml file by injecting the ServiceConfiguration here as shown above. But the problem I am facing is that the above class is initialized before the bootstrap's run method is called, and since the ServiceConfiguration is made available by the run method, the value of ServiceConfiguration I am getting in the above class is null. 
Please help how I should resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In the application.yml file, I am passing some parameters under logging -> appenders, and then I could access these parameters in my custom class that extends logging factory. From there I could use the parameters in my custom JSON layout class.